# React Route rendering wrong component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using `react-router-dom@5.2.0` for routing and I'm having some trouble with the react routing.

Here is my app.js render code:

```
return (
  <div>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Context>
        {/* Students */}
        <Route exact path='/student'><Home /></Route>
        <Route path='/student/signup'><SignupScreen /></Route>

        {/* Tutors */}
        <Route path='/tutor/signup'><TSignupScreen /></Route>
      </Context>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </div>
);
```

When I visit `"/student"` route it renders student signup component but the url is not changing. you can see the image below
[image]

Comment: Yes home is just a screen. ig im running latest code

Comment: Sanket has it below in their answer. Routers *inclusively* render all matching routes by default, using a `Switch` will now *exclusively* match routes.

Comment: What version of React are you running? You can check by running `npm list react` in the terminal. May as well confirm the installed version of `react-router-dom` as well, run `npm list react react-router-dom` and report back the installed versions. If you can, please see if you can create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue you describe that we can inspect live.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap all your routes inside [`Switch`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch), which renders the first child  that matches the location.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
...
<BrowserRouter>
    <Context>
      <Switch>
      {/* Students */}
      <Route exact path='/student'><Home /> </Route>
      <Route path='/student/signup' > <SignupScreen /> </Route>

      {/* Tutors */}
      <Route path='/tutor/signup'> <TSignupScreen />  </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Context>
 </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: its still not working for me i am using react-router-dom .

Comment: Is there any code in the `Home` component that redirects students to the `Student Sign Up` component if they are not logged in and trying to access `Home` component without logged in ? @NaveenRavi

Comment: no no . i just created home and it does not contain any logic it just  contain some html

Comment: This should then work. Can you provide a CodeSandbox link or anything? I'm guessing the problem is something else.